# placing file in folder with number in python

Tags: python, directory, wildcard

I am just beginning with python and I'm trying to place a file inside a directory. The directory has a name with a number behind it that changes depending on the creation date. The function I'm using for placing the file takes only the directory + the file as an argument. So an argument for the function could be: `C:\Program Files\example241\file.txt`,  `C:\Program Files\example948\file.txt` etc. How would I place the file in that folder no mather what number it has? Could I use a wildcard?

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to move a file from a particular directory to the directory corresponding to today's date?

Comment: do you know the number or is there only one `exampleN` directory?

Comment: I'm sorry I was not clear. I am basically trying to place a file in whatever directory exists on that persons pc that begins with a certain word. So if the directory example827 exists, place the file in there and do the same if the folders name ends with 382 or 230 or 132 etc.

Comment: You can use `os` to get a list of all files in your current directory, and then you can search the list to find where you want to move/copy the file. When you have a list of the directories where you want to place the files, you can easily copy the source file to the destination(s) using `shutil.copyfile()`.

Comment: In order to extract the names of the directories, you can simply iterate over the list of all files, you get from `os.listdir()`, and then search for the keyword, which in your case is - example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module

```
from glob import glob
# this gives all the folders that answer to this pattern 
folders = glob(r'C:\Program Files\example*')  
folder = folders[0]  # pick the first one
```

append the desired file name with the os module

```
import os
file_name = 'file.txt'
file_path = os.path.join(folder, file_name)
```

and then save the file to `file_path`